# Django: limit API view output to contain only data of OAuth authenticated user?

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-rest-framework

My app requires user consent to use activity data from his Strava account (Strava is a social service for athletes).

Strava uses OAuth flow for this, so the user logs in to Strava, gives his consent, and Strava redirects to a predefined URL with code added to query string that can be then exchanged for access token via another request:

```
def strava_redirects_to_this_view(request):
    #strava redirects to this view after authentication, with code in query string

    #get tokens
    code = request.GET.get('code', '') # extract code from redirect URL query string
    access_token = exchange_code_for_token(code) # custom function to make exchange request
```

I want my other app - running on another server - to get data of only authenticated user via API.

However, I don't know how to limit the output of the API to contain only the data of the currently authenticated user.

Currently my API view queries all data (activities), regardless of user:

```
class ListActivitiesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
```

I know I could limit the queryset to only logged in user if I had user registration in my app, but I would prefer not to have another registration as the user already has to log in to Strava.

How would I limit the `queryset` to include only currently OAuth authenticated user? Would use of `python-social-auth` with Strava backend be of any help here?

Comment: Can't you use a request query param to the api endpoint when redirecting the user or some cache for limiting the fields you could check out https://github.com/wimglenn/djangorestframework-queryfields

Comment: The thing is the API is called from another app - on another server - that knows nothing about which user is currently authenticated, so it cannot send anything as query parameter.